# Advanced scenarios with BackstopJS

Tags: javascript, css

I'm experimenting with BackstopJS and I'm having trouble figuring out how to get a test for an hover element.

backstop.json

```
{
  "id": "backstop_default",
  "viewports": [
    {
      "label": "phone",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 480
    },
    {
      "label": "tablet",
      "width": 1024,
      "height": 768
    }
  ],
  "onBeforeScript": "chromy/onBefore.js",
  "onReadyScript": "chromy/onReady.js",
  "scenarios": [
    {
      "label": "My Local Test",
      "url": "../../index.html",
      "hideSelectors": [],
      "removeSelectors": [
      ],
      "selectors": [
        "nav",
        ".jumbotron",
        "body .col-md-4:nth-of-type(1)",
        "body .col-md-4:nth-of-type(2)",
        "body .col-md-4:nth-of-type(3)",
        "footer",
        ".btn-default"
      ],
      "hoverSelector": [
        ".btn-default"
      ],
      "readyEvent": null,
      "delay": 0,
      "onReadyScript": null,
      "onBeforeScript": null
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "bitmaps_reference": "backstop_data/bitmaps_reference",
    "bitmaps_test": "backstop_data/bitmaps_test",
    "engine_scripts": "backstop_data/engine_scripts",
    "html_report": "backstop_data/html_report",
    "ci_report": "backstop_data/ci_report"
  },
  "report": ["browser"],
  "engine": "chrome",
  "engineFlags": [],
  "asyncCaptureLimit": 5,
  "asyncCompareLimit": 50,
  "debug": false,
  "debugWindow": false
}
```

The `btn-default` is the button element that has a hover on it. Currently I only get a reference from the normal `btn-default` button. The `hoverSelector` doesn't seen to do anything.

The docs say:

> hoverSelector // Move the pointer over the specified DOM element prior to screen shot (available with default onReadyScript)

Am I misunderstanding the use of `hoverSelector`?

Answer (score 0):

in my backstop.json hoverSelector is not an array
try to change

```
    "hoverSelector": [
    ".btn-default"
  ],
```

to

```
    "hoverSelector": ".btn-default",
```

If you refer to the latest backstopjs documentation for the backstop.json file, hoverSelector is not an array.

https://github.com/garris/BackstopJS